# Marking good and bad takes to help in editing

Tags: editing

I've been learning about using different numbers of claps or finger-clicks when shooting my video/audio, so that later in editing they can act as markers as to which takes were good and which can just be ignored.[1] I'm not sure this approach would be used in a multi-person pro environment, but it's in a course on making videos by yourself and I'm finding it really useful since it means I don't have to stop/re-start my camera and sound every time I screw up in my dialog (which is *a lot*)

So, for example, you might use three claps to mark the end of a good take. That way, when it comes to editing time, you can scan through the audio channel and know that you can ignore any sections not ending with the three tell-tale audio spikes.

My question is: **Is there any kind of *standard* or more comprehensive approach to this?**

I guess I'm wondering if there's maybe any kind of overall system of "clap codes" that would include not only the 3-clap "*Good Take*" indicator but also have, for example, a 2-clap "*Mostly Good Take*" one. So suppose you were recording yourself speaking a long block of dialog but you screwed up on the very last line. Rather than re-take the whole thing, you might just immediately bash on and try to repair it, re-doing only the messed up last line (and maybe the one or two preceding it), with the intention of then stitching both parts together later, in post. So you'd get something like the following:

**[CLAP!]**

```
Lots and
lots and
...
lots of dialog
Second last line
Last line but we made a mistake
```

**[CLAP! x 2]**

```
Second last line
Last line done correctly this time
```

**[CLAP! x 3]**

---

[1] Note that this is in addition to the standard single audio/video sync clap/click inserted at the start of a take.